# Node js API in production server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, putty

I need to run node.js API which saved in Production server. In local server, it works perfectly but in live it show error that '*site cant be reached*'. We are using server **Linux apache** of godaddy. Node.js is successfully installed in server.I am using **Putty** as terminal in windows.

I dont know why this happen when it comes to live. No error in code. Is there any changes need to **URL** that we run? And am testing result in **Postman**.
The basic code is given below and I test url it with "127.0.0.0.1:3000"(doesnt work). I recheck it with replacing IP with server IP, system IP, localhost but no result. 
Thanks in advance.

> var http = require('http');
>
> http.createServer(function (req, res) {
>
> res.write('Hello World!');
>
> res.end();
>
> }).listen(3000);

Comment: Please check if port 3000 is open in linux firewall.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it with several ports, but no result. I dont know how to open port.

Comment: **127.0.0.0.1:3000** too much 0
just **127.0.0.1:3000** . **172.0.0.1** , **0.0.0.0** , and **localhost** is the same.

Comment: These all I tried but no change :( . The same error is happened.

Comment: Any one please help
I use godaddy shared server
I have installed in node js. it works and no error in putty
but i run in browser the page is loading finally it says time out error but no error in putty